# What happens internally on knex.transaction()

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I would like to add a knex transaction to my request parameter from a middleware for every incoming request.

How is the performance of knex.transaction()? Does it do something costly like opening a database connection?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I suggest you first read something about [transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) and then think about when and how you should use them in your application

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I know how to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knex transactions are opened eagerly. So when you call `knex.transaction` it immediately reserves database connection from the pool, even if you are not sending any queries there.

Also if you are creating that implicitly opened transaction, remember to make sure that it will get committed / rolled back. Otherwise they will remain alive after request is handled and fill up the connection pool.

So instead of always opening transaction you might consider exposing `req.trx()`middleware, which will create singleton transaction lazily when you call it for the first time...